# is there a way of including firebase authentication in Quasar Composition API?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vuejs3, quasar

I am a beginner in Quasar framework and i find it interested because it has a good and friendly user interface.Recently i initialized a project and wanted to intergrate it completely with firebase without using axios and vuex . Below is how i tried to implement the firebase authentication with the vue router :

```
        <template>
  <div class="home">
    <q-card align="center" flat>
    <q-card class="my-card">
    
      
      
    <q-form @submit.prevent="Login" method="post" ref="myForm">
    <h4>Login</h4>
    <img :src="image">
    
   <q-input
   square clearable
        filled
        v-model="email"
        label="Your email *"
        hint="email"
        suffix="@gmail.com"
        lazy-rules
        :rules="[ val => val && val.length > 0 || 'Please type something']"
      ><template v-slot:prepend>
                  <q-icon name="email" />
                </template></q-input>
     

       <q-input square clearable v-model="password" filled :type="isPwd ? 'password' : 'text'" hint="Password">
        <template v-slot:prepend>
                  <q-icon name="lock" />
                </template>
        <template v-slot:append>
          <q-icon
            :name="isPwd ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'"
            class="cursor-pointer"
            @click="isPwd = !isPwd"
            lazy-rules
            :rules="[ val => val && val.length > 0 || 'Please type something']"
          />
            </template>
      </q-input>
      <q-btn label="Sign in" type="submit" color="primary"/>
      <q-space/>
      <q-toolbar flat>
      <router-link to="/help">Forget Password</router-link>
      <q-space/>
      <router-link to="/create">Create New Account</router-link>
      </q-toolbar>

  
</q-form>
    
    </q-card>
    </q-card>
    
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import {ref} from 'vue'
import image from '../assets/login.jpg'
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router' // import router




export default {
   
    setup () {

    const email = ref('')
const password = ref('')
const errMsg = ref() // ERROR MESSAGE

const router = useRouter() // get a reference to our vue router

const signIn = () => { // we also renamed this method 
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(getAuth(),email.value, password.value) // THIS LINE CHANGED
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('Successfully logged in!');
      router.push('/feed') // redirect to the feed
    })
    .catch(error => {
      switch (error.code) {
        case 'auth/invalid-email':
            errMsg.value = 'Invalid email'
            break
        case 'auth/user-not-found':
            errMsg.value = 'No account with that email was found'
            break
        case 'auth/wrong-password':
            errMsg.value = 'Incorrect password'
            break  
        default:
            errMsg.value = 'Email or password was incorrect'
            break
      }
    });
    return {
      password: ref(''),
      isPwd: ref(true),
      image:image,
      signIn
      
      
    
      
      
    }
    }
    
  }
}
```

.my-card
    width: 100%
    max-width: 450px

Answer (score 0):

I too enjoy the Quasar framework but there are a few things that take some getting used to as it is a framework on top of a framework.  I would suggest reviewing the VueJS docs if you have not already before proceeding much further with Quasar to help understand how the two frameworks interact.

Now, to your markup...

In this instance, you do not need to wrap your input in a form or 'q-form' for this to work. You certainly do not need the ref or method type as you are not actually calling these at any point in your logic.

It appears you also named the submit function on your form "Login" but in your logic is called "signIn" so when you submit, the function is not firing.

Your form could look like this:

```html
<q-form @submit.prevent="signIn">
  ... input elements...
  <q-btn type="submit" label="sign in" />
</q-form>
```

Or without the 'q-form' wrapper...

```html
 ... input elements...

 <q-btn @click.prevent="signIn" label="sign in" />
```

These will both work the same, as will the Quasar validation checking.  Now on to your logic...

You will also want to check that a user was returned from the response and not just data. A response will always be returned, but it may not be a valid login and yet the router will still push. (I would also suggest using the 'router.replace' method instead of 'push' so if the user hits the back button, it doesn't return the Login Page).

Your logic could look something like this:

```js
import { appConfig } from './someplace/where/your/firebase/credentials/are'

export default {
  setup() {
    const email = ref(null);
    const password = ref(null);
    const errMsg = ref(null);
    const isPwd = ref(true);
    const router = useRouter();
    const auth = getAuth(appConfig);

    const signIn = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          auth,
          email.value,
          password.value
        );
        const user = data.user;
        if (user) {
          router.replace("/feed");
        }   // NOTE there is an implicit 'else' here. Not necessary with ES6
        return  // OR console.log('something') if you prefer
      } catch (error) {
        switch (error.code) {
          case "auth/invalid-email":
            errMsg.value = "Invalid email";
            break;
          case "auth/user-not-found":
            errMsg.value = "No account with that email was found";
            break;
          case "auth/wrong-password":
            errMsg.value = "Incorrect password";
            break;
          default:
            errMsg.value = "Email or password was incorrect";
            break;
        }
      }
    };
    return {
      password,
      email,
      isPwd,
      image,
      signIn,
      errMsg,
    };
  },
};
```

You also need to pass the configuration of your firebase app to the 'getAuth' function.  This is usually where you call the 'initializeApp' function probably in a firebase.js file or as a Quasar boot file.

Finally, review the Firebase docs regarding 'onAuthStateChanged' if you need to collect or interact with user data in another part of your app.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but encountering Must use '. value' to read or write the value wrapped by 'ref()' vue/no-ref-as-operand

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  Either pass 'user.value' to the if() statement or remove the ref() and declare the user variable within your signIn method depending on your needs.  See my edit if you need clarification.

Comment: thanks i successfully fixed it but i am having trouble saving and fetching data

Comment: Can you share your console errors?

Comment: It is too long to be added in the comment here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74309205/how-do-i-add-data-into-my-firebase-through-vuex-4 here is the link of the question